# How to use the count() method on a list excluding some items

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

So, I want to if, in a list, there are any repeated numbers, but I want to exclude some of them. How can I do it, using the count() method? Can I?

Example:

```
thelist = [0,0,3,4]

for x in thelist:
    if thelist.count(x) > 1:
            print("Repeated")
            break
```

Obviously it says repeated. Now, how can I avoid counting the zeros? I just want it to count the following numbers:

```
only_numbers_the_function_should_test = [1,2,3,4]
```

I've searched through the web and found nothing. Maybe it's impossible. Can you give me an alternative?

Note : I don't want it to remove any list item. It's for a sudoku solver. I can't cut numbers like that.

Comment: `if x in [1,2,3,4] and thelist.count(x) > 1:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick in an if condition.

```
for x in thelist:
    if x==0:
        continue
    # rest of your code
```

Or if you want a specific range:

```
if x <= 0 or x > 9:
    continue
```

Comment: Both of the work fine. I think I'll stick with the first one. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: If you think it's the write answer and solves the problem, go ahead and mark it with the tick, so it comes up as solved.

Comment: Hahaha I know, it was just that I couldn't due to timing issues.

Comment: @JamesJenkinson, you can specify ranges also like this: ` if 0 <= x < 9:` or even `if x in range(10):`

Comment: If you're doing `if x in range(10)` you're iterating over an entire range, it's much less efficient. I'd forgotten that range syntax, but most languages look much more like the normal way anyway. The whole point of python is readable code. I think using syntax similar to the majority of c-like languages is more readable. Just one guy's opinion.

Comment: And if you're going to go over a range, `xrange(n)` is wayyyyy more efficient, and not prone to crashing you're programs if you put in 10000.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't filter the `0`s out of the list first and then count:

```
from collections import Counter
thelist = [0, 0, 3, 4]
counter = Counter([x for x in l if x != 0])
for i in Counter([x for x in thelist if x != 0]):
    if counter[i] > 1:
        print("Repeated")
```

**EDIT**: With a simple modification to your code

```
thelist = [0,0,3,4]

for x in [x for x in thelist if x != 0]:
    if thelist.count(x) > 1:
       print("Repeated")
       break
```

Comment: I had read about that solution, but it seemed quite complicated to me and I didn't want to import modules if I could avoid it. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ok you can avid importing modules, you could make a simple modification to the code you posted and also its done.